# FreeBSD Bash - Unable to code a condition with regex

Tags: regex, bash, freebsd

I am trying to code a script for pfSense who is based on FreeBSD.  The only part left who is giving me trouble is a condition with a regex.  The simplified code is this :

```
RESPONSE='{"port":98989}'
REG='{"port":([0-9]*)}'
if [[ $RESPONSE =~ $REG ]]; then
    PORT=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

With the trace mode enabled, the error returned is the following :

```
+ RESPONSE='{"port":98989}'
+ REG='{"port":([0-9]*)}'
+ '[[' '{"port":98989}' '=~' '{"port":([0-9]*)}' ]]
./pia-port-v2: [[: not found
```

I don't understand why the `[[` is between single quote in the trace and it is probably why the "not found" error occurs.

**Update**

It is probably because pfSense's FreeBSD does not support bash and these instructions are bash only.  I found that after writing this question and trying to find an answer.

Anybody have an alternative for bourne shell?  The goal is to return the port number if the expression match.

I am new to script coding in unix like OS.

In the meantime, I look at grep, but it seems to apply the regex to file input only.

Comment: Works fine on OS X -- a variant of BSD. BTW -- Please use lower case for user variables as a matter of convention.

Comment: Not relevant but worth noting: DO NOT use all-caps variable names in shell scripts. Those are reserved for the system and the shell implementation (which is why you see so many of them). Your own variables should be written normally in lower-case.

Comment: @rici - Already noted.

Comment: Note: Bash is not the default shell on FreeBSD. POSIX sh and tcsh are available in the base system. Unless you install a bash package you should not be using Bash-specific constructs like `[[` and `=~`. See the [sh(1) manual](https://man.freebsd.org/sh) to see what the syntax is.

Comment: Are you sure you execute this script with `bash`?  The default shell on FreeBSD (i.e. what is installed as `sh`) is not a `bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`expr` utility](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=expr&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%205.0-RELEASE) to do this, but note that it use [Posix *basic* regexps](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), which means that you need to backslash your parentheses to make them into captures:

```
response='{"port":98989}'
reg='{"port":\([0-9]*\)}'
port=$(expr "$response" : "$reg")
```

`expr` returns failure if the regex doesn't match, so you could use a shell conditional to test:

```
port=$(expr "$response" : "$reg") || { echo Failed; }
```

or

```
if ! port=$(expr "$response" : "$reg"); then
  # Do something on failure
fi
```

Comment: It do the job!  It returns correctly the port number.  For the condition part, I only have to check if port is empty.  Thanks!

Comment: @sbeaudoin: You can check for failure of the assignment. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With `/bin/sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

response='{"port":98989}'
case $response in
    '{"port":'[0-9]*'}')
        port=${response#*:}     # {"port":98989} --> 98989}
        port=${port%'}'}        # 98989} --> 98989
esac

printf 'response %s yields port %s\n' "$response" "$port"
```

Note that a `case` statement does not use regular expression but shell filename globbing patterns.  Therefore, the pattern will only match a single digit and trigger for bogus strings like `{"port":0xxx}`.

If the response string is a JSON document:

```
$ response='{"port":98989}'
$ printf '%s\n' "$response" | jq .port
98989
```

Comment: This works also, except the jq part.  It gives a "jq: not found".

Comment: @sbeaudoin Yes, you would need to install the `jq` port: https://www.freshports.org/textproc/jq/

Answer (score -3):

There is trouble with ' and " when using [[ regexps (sometimes; not always) so I would try this instead (which works fine for me):

```
#!/bin/bash

REG=\{\"port\"\:\([0-9]\*\)\}  # This line is altered
RESPONSE='{"port":98989}'
if [[ $RESPONSE =~ $REG ]]; then
  echo funkar
fi
```

Comment: It gives me "Command not found" and then it hit me.  It must be because pfSense's FreeBSD does not support bash.  My question as been updated.

Comment: My code runs in sh as well so just replace #!/bin/bash with #!/bin/sh

Comment: not in pfSense, it gives the same symptoms.  The script is exactly what you wrote except the first line.  Mine reads "#!/bin/sh -x".

Comment: No I altered the REG= line (removed ' ')

Comment: @jonas: On your machine, /bin/sh is implemented with bash. But that's not the case on all installations. You should never make that assumption.

Comment: @jonas, what I mean is : my test script is exatly the whole content you wrote except for the first line.